Missing number, treated as zero error in latex in begin enumerate
I am getting the following error in \begin{enumerate} environment: missing number treated as zero. I am using the following code.
\documentclass[11pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath,textcomp,  microtype, lmodern, mathrsfs,csquotes,fbb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
  
\usepackage{hyperref}
       
\usepackage{url} 
           
\usepackage{booktabs}  
    
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
      
\usepackage{nicefrac} 
       
\usepackage{microtype} 
    
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
  
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{showkeys}[notref,notcite]
\usepackage{dutchcal}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}

\newtheorem{calculation}[theorem]{Calculation}

\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}

\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\newenvironment{claim}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Claim:}\space#1}{}

\newenvironment{claimproof}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Proof:}\space#1}{\hfill $\blacksquare$}

\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}

\newtheorem{exer}[theorem]{Exercise}

\newtheorem{sketch}[theorem]{sketch}

\newtheorem{spec}[theorem]{Speculation}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcommand{\V}{\Vert}
\newcommand{\mnote}[1]{\marginpar{\tiny\bf #1}}

\newcommand{\stnote}[1]{\marginpar{\tiny\bf #1}}


this is enumerate code
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Roman*)]
\item\label{limsup}
\(
-\gamma_\psi - \frac{1}{k} \leq \frac{r_\psi(t_k)}{nt_k} \leq -\gamma_\psi + \frac{1}{k};
\)
\item\label{aftertk}
\(
\forall t\geq t_k,\quad r_\psi(t) \leq r_\psi(t_k) + R_1M_k;
\)
\item 
\(
 r_\psi(t_k-R_1M_k) \leq r_\psi(t_k) + \frac{1+\gamma}{2}R_1M_k.
\)
\end{enumerate}


Please minimise your example: at present there is a lot of extra code.

Not only have you posted a lot of code unrelated to your question, you have not included any example of your problem, there is no \begin{enumerate} here.

I added  three backticks before and after your code to make it a code block (but the code is still unrelated to your question)

don't add another diconnected fragment make a small complete document that shows your problem, if you can show the problem without  \usepackage{pdfpages} then delete it from the example (I assume you will be able to delete almost every line of the first code block)

You have not provided a usable example but  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\Roman*)] appears to be using the syntax of the enumitem package which you have not used.
Replace \usepackage{enumerate} by \usepackage{enumitem}

The code posted should always be an example of the problem, a more reasonable example here, that you could have made by deleting lines from the preamble while still showing the error is
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Roman*)]
\item x
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

which produces the error
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@* 
l.7 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\Roman*)]
                                      
? 


It worked, thanks a lot

@user3333 please see my updated comment on examples, for next time you ask here
